# Regex to find duplicate instances of text in single field on one row MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex, vb.net

There are several questions around asking how to find duplicate rows, but that is not what I need.

I have a products database which includes a field `description` which contains encoded HTML descriptions of the item.

This content is generated by a back end system which uses TinyMCE to create HTML descriptions.

Users have on occasion entered several instances of H tags which I am trying to locate.

So I am looking for any descriptions which contain either:

- More than one H1 tag
- More than one H2 tag
- More than one H3 tag

This regex `\b(\w+)\b(?=.*\b\1\b)/g` locates duplicate words in a string, but I am not sure how to use it to find specific words.

SO, if a description field in any row in my database looks like this:

```
  &lt;h1&gt;this is a header&lt;/h1&gt; 
  Here is some text about stuff
  &lt;h1&gt;here is another header&lt;/h1&gt;
```

How would I find it?

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE description *CONTAINS &lt;h1&gt; AND &lt;/h1&gt; TWICE*
```

Comment: mysql regexes don't support capturing. you'd need to repeat whatever you want duplicate. e.g. `where foo contains 'bar.*bar'`

Comment: Marc B, could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an MySQL instance to test against, and this might be naive on my part, but I think you can probably do this using a simple wildcard test for both values. Regex would be more sophisticated, but a wildcard would be more portable, easier for someone else other than you to understand and, based on how regex works, possibly faster (you would need to test this).

```
SELECT 
   * 
FROM 
   products 
WHERE 
   description LIKE '%&lt;h1&gt;%&lt;h1&gt;%' OR
   description LIKE '%&lt;h2&gt;%h2&gt;%' OR
   description LIKE '%&lt;h3&gt;%&lt;h3&gt;%'
```

I haven't had a chance to test this, but it works against my local CMS (albeit, not running on MySQL).

Comment: That will just find if the H tags appear, I need to find if the same H tag appears more than once in the text.

Comment: If you look carefully at my answer, you'll see that I'm actually checking for more than one instance. I'll break out one line of the where clause for you:  `'%&lt;h1&gt;%&lt;h1&gt;%'` : `%` first wild operator, this will match any content leading up to the first <h1> tag; `&lt;h1&gt;` first instance of the <h1> tag (with HTML entites for the <,> characters); `%` second wildcard operator -- this will match any content between the first <h1> tag and the second <h1> tag; `&lt;h1&gt;` the second instance of the <h1> tag; `%` last wildcard operator -- matches all content to the end of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE description REGEXP '(h1+|h2+|h3+)'
```

h1+, mean 1 or more matches, and | Match either of the sequences h1, h2 or h3

Comment: Can I modify that to find it with the angled brackets and for TWICE or more? I don't need to know if it appears once.